# Segmentation fault (core dumped) with strcpy

Tags: c

I'v encountered "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" when compile my C program in *nix. I've narrowed the mistake to this line (without this line my program can run):

```
strcpy(con[count], "1234");
```

Before that, I declared con as:

```
char *con[30];
```

And count is always smaller than 30.

What's wrong with this line? How should I change it?

Comment: you want `char con[30]`

Comment: Also: your target should be the array (`con`) and not (`con[count]`) - what is `count` supposed to do here in your opinion?

Comment: Well as declared it is an array of `char*`, but even so the indexing is off-by-one. And presumably the buffer isn't even allocated yet.

Comment: You either want `char con[30]` or `con[count] = (char *)malloc(length); strcpy(con[count], "1234");`

Comment: Depends if you want an array of strings (`char *`) or if you just want a simple string.

Comment: Without code there's no way to tell, but odds are you have allocated any memory for that pointer.

Answer (score 2):

```
char *con[30];
```

declares an array of 30 pointers to strings. This is not what you need. It fails because you then try to copy to the first string, but did not allocate the first string (only a pointer to it)

You need

```
char con[30];
```

and then

```
strcpy(con, "1234");
```

Or (as Lee Danial points out) you might have wanted an array , in which case you need

```
 char *con[30];
```

then

```
con[count] = strdup("1234")
```

or

```
con[count] = "1234"
```

The first one allocates a string and copies it for you (a combination of malloc and strcpy). The second one just points at the supplied literal, it doesn't make a copy. Hard to say which is 'best' for you.

PS strdup is equivalent to

```
  x = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
    strcpy(x, str);
    return x;
```

Comment: Or else he does mean to have an array of strings, in which case he just needs to allocate memory for them (perhaps with strdup())

Comment: Thanks, I use con[count] = "1234" and it's fine now. But than when I print it with line printf("%s\n", con[count]); the segmentation fault occurs again. How can I print it?

Comment: @Eileen you have to ask a new question - showing all your code, not just spinnets